# Powers of 10 written as binary numbers

Tags: binary

Consider powers of 10 written as binary numbers.

10 = 1**0**10 , 100 = 11**00**100 , 1000 = 11111**0**1000

How can I find a formula for the number of zeroes between the last and the second last 1?

Comment: You do know that you may concentrate on powers of $5$, right? Then you won't have to deal with the trailing zeroes.

Comment: One may as well compute the same for the powers $5^k$ of $5$, whose binary expressions are the same as those for $10$, but with the $k$ zeros at the end of the sequence truncated.

Comment: So it's one less than the greatest power of $2$ which exactly divides $5^n-1$.

Comment: @Jack Wother: Your comment shows that you have not understood the first two comments! Look at powers of $5$ in binary, and you will see what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the comments: the answer, let's call it $f(n)$, is one less than the greatest power of $2$ which divides $5^n-1$.  Thus $$f(n)=v_2(5^n-1)-1$$  where, as usual, $v_2(k)$ denotes the greatest power of $2$ dividing $k$.

To compute $v_2(5^n-1)$...

first note that this is $2$ if $n$ is odd:  indeed $5^n-1=(5-1)(5^{n-1}+\dots+1)$ regardless of the parity of $n$ and, if $n$ is odd the second factor is easily seen to be odd.

If $n=2k$ is even then $$5^n-1=5^{2k}-1=(5^k-1)(5^k+1)$$  Now, the second factor here is even (clearly) but is never divisible by $4$ (as $5^k=1$ mod($4$)). It follows that $$v_2(5^{2k}-1)=v_2(5^k-1)+1$$

Combining these remarks one sees that, for $n=2^km$ with $m$ odd we have $$v_2(5^{2^km}-1)=2+k$$

thus, the final answer is $$f(n)=f(2^km)=k+1$$

Comment: One might want to look it up on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A085058), too.

Comment: Thank you for replying. There is one thing that I do not understand is that why would the function be  _f(n)=v2(5n−1)−1_ as defined? Many thanks once again

Comment: No problem.  This is equivalent to what appears in the posted solution of @YvesDaoust .  Starting, as you did, with $10^n$, you kill off the trailing $0's$.  That's equivalent to dividing by $2^n$, which gets you to $5^n$.  Now $5^n$ is clearly odd, so its binary expansion ends in $1$.  I remove that $1$ by subtracting it off, he removes it by dividing by $2$ and discarding the fractional remainder.  Sticking with my subtraction, you now want the number of trailing $0's$ in $5^n-1$, less one because you don't count the right most slot (that was taken up by the final $1$ before subtraction).

Comment: Continuing...the number of training $0's$ in the binary expansion of $m$ is precisely $v_2(m)$ so we are done.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been fantastic. I understand it completely now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the number of trailing zeroes at the end of $5^p/2$ (integer division). In mathematical terms, it is the multiplicity of the factor $2$ in the prime decomposition of this number.

In programming, you will shift right until you get an odd number, and count the shifts.